# unexpected indent error inside a definition for a function

Tags: python

I have this code for the movement of a monster to move randomly between rooms but I get an unexpected intention error for the global value.

```
def monster(): """moves the monster randomly"""
    global monster_current_room
    if monster_current_room["name"] != current_room:
        print('The monster is currently in', monster_current_room["name"])
        exits = list(monster_current_room["exits"].values())
        if random.randint(1, 4) == 4:
            monster_current_room = rooms[random.choice(exits)]
    elif monster_current_room["name"] == current_room:
        game_over = True
```

if I unindent the global value it acts as the end of the definition and wants two lines between the definition and global value. when I try to run with the indent the program fails with the error.

Comment: Send the full code and remove the last sentence from the code block

Comment: @Vittorio is that what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the function comment:

```py
def monster(): 
    """
    moves the monster randomly
    """
    global monster_current_room
    if monster_current_room["name"] != current_room:
        print('The monster is currently in', monster_current_room["name"])
        exits = list(monster_current_room["exits"].values())
        if random.randint(1, 4) == 4:
            monster_current_room = rooms[random.choice(exits)]
    elif monster_current_room["name"] == current_room:
        game_over = True
```

or if you prefer an inline comment you can do like that

```py
def monster(): # moves the monster randomly
    global monster_current_room
    if monster_current_room["name"] != current_room:
        print('The monster is currently in', monster_current_room["name"])
        exits = list(monster_current_room["exits"].values())
        if random.randint(1, 4) == 4:
            monster_current_room = rooms[random.choice(exits)]
    elif monster_current_room["name"] == current_room:
        game_over = True
```

when you write a multiline string like

```py
"""
moves the monster randomly
"""
```

it has to respect the rules of the classic sentences of the python code. So you can't place them whenever you want like comments.